# How to get rails master.key after upgrading to rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

So I've upgraded an app I'm working on to rails 5.2 and it's crashing on Heroku. I think it's because I don't have a master.key file in my /config folder. I still have the secrets.yml file from the previous rails version. What do I have to do to resolve this issue?
Thanks!

error in heroku logs:

```
2019-01-28T21:07:46.922561+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.30.1/lib/aws-sdk-s3/bucket.rb:684:in `extract_name': Cannot load `Rails.config.active_storage.service`: (ArgumentError)
2019-01-28T21:07:46.922573+00:00 app[web.1]: missing required option :name
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to generate **master.key** and **credentials.yml.enc**. To do this, just run the command:

```
run EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit
```

(As editor you can use something else, for example atom or nano).

In opening editor, you can type credentials, and save it. Rails use **master.key** to encrypt credentials. More you can find here: https://medium.com/cedarcode/rails-5-2-credentials-9b3324851336

To make encrypted credentials work on Heroku, you can copy key from master.key and use it to set up `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` environemnt variable. You can achieve this by Heroku Dashboard or Heroku CLI, as below:

```
$ heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=`cat config/master.key`
```

Comment: You will also need to set ```config.require_master_key = true``` in ```config/environments/production.rb```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things.  Speaking from my own personal experience, I've upgraded several Rails apps to 5.2 and I have been able to deploy to Heroku just fine without this feature.  So I don't think its that necessarily.

If you could run `heroku logs --tail --app <your app name>` and show us a stack trace of why your app is failing, that would definitely help.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help I added what seems to be causing the crash in the logs. Is this helpful?

Comment: Thanks.  I'd run `rake app:update` for sure.  That looks like a generic error that has to do with ActiveStorage.  Perhaps your initializers aren't updated or you're missing some of the newer initializers?

Comment: I ran the command but the same error is still appearing. If it is my initializers what can I do to fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to generate master.key file by using following command:

```
$ EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit
```

It's sample output will be as follows:

```
Adding config/master.key to store the master encryption key: <YOUR_MASTER_KEY>

Save this in a password manager your team can access.

If you lose the key, no one, including you, can access anything encrypted with it.

      create  config/master.key

Ignoring config/master.key so it won't end up in Git history:

      append  .gitignore
```

Please check official documentation:  https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/commands/credentials/USAGE