# Heroku Twitter api app deployment with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, twitter-oauth

I am new to Ruby and Rails in general and am following this series

https://gorails.com/episodes/rails-for-beginners-part-38-deploying-to-heroku

I have this weird issue where is everything seems to work fine except connecting my app with

Twitter Api.

I did everything to connect successfully but nothing seems working!

I added the website link to Twitter developer callbacks urls which are

https://jadwlh.herokuapp.com/

along with

https://jadwlh.herokuapp.com/auth/twitter/callback

I added both

API_KEY

and

API_SECRET

to Config Vars.

I even changed SECRET_KEY_BASE in Config Vars

to the one provided in the credentials file in my app!

Even though tried everything, still got this message shown in the image below when I try to

connect my app with Twitter  Api

[image]

routes.rb file

```
# For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  #GET /about
  get "about", to: "about#index"

  get "password", to: "passwords#edit", as: :edit_password
  patch "password", to: "passwords#update"

  get "sign_up", to: "registrations#new"
  post "sign_up", to: "registrations#create"

  delete "logout", to: "sessions#destroy"

  get "sign_in", to: "sessions#new"
  post "sign_in", to: "sessions#create"

  get "password/reset", to: "password_resets#new"
  post "password/reset", to: "password_resets#create"
  get "password/reset/edit", to: "password_resets#edit"
  patch "password/reset/edit", to: "password_resets#update"

  get "/auth/twitter/callback", to: "omniauth_callbacks#twitter"

  resources :twitter_accounts
  resources :tweets

  # get "/", to: "main#index"
  root to: "main#index"
end
```

Application logs

```
2021-05-31T06:15:04.415968+00:00 app[web.1]: [13f44544-8fd2-4348-8b08-1191ad53716b]   
2021-05-31T06:15:04.418156+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/auth/failure?message=session_expired&strategy=twitter" host=jadwlh.herokuapp.com request_id=13f44544-8fd2-4348-8b08-1191ad53716b fwd="217.182.175.162" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=180 protocol=https
2021-05-31T06:15:31.243002+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-05-31T06:15:31.242901 #4]  INFO -- : [c5f8ff8c-58fa-439d-a9f3-e08047bc5aa8] Started POST "/auth/twitter" for 46.152.103.96 at 2021-05-31 06:15:31 +0000
2021-05-31T06:15:31.243645+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-05-31T06:15:31.243583 #4] DEBUG -- omniauth: (twitter) Request phase initiated.
2021-05-31T06:15:31.388564+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2021-05-31T06:15:31.388453 #4] ERROR -- omniauth: (twitter) Authentication failure! 400 Bad Request: OAuth::Unauthorized, 400 Bad Request
2021-05-31T06:15:31.390962+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/auth/twitter" host=jadwlh.herokuapp.com request_id=c5f8ff8c-58fa-439d-a9f3-e08047bc5aa8 fwd="46.152.103.96" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=150ms status=302 bytes=834 protocol=https
2021-05-31T06:15:31.574904+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/failure?message=400+Bad+Request&strategy=twitter" host=jadwlh.herokuapp.com request_id=3adfd6f0-58b9-47c3-ab04-017161a56e18 fwd="46.152.103.96" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=1902 protocol=https
2021-05-31T06:15:31.571195+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-05-31T06:15:31.571067 #4]  INFO -- : [3adfd6f0-58b9-47c3-ab04-017161a56e18] Started GET "/auth/failure?message=400+Bad+Request&strategy=twitter" for 46.152.103.96 at 2021-05-31 06:15:31 +0000
2021-05-31T06:15:31.572790+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2021-05-31T06:15:31.572717 #4] FATAL -- : [3adfd6f0-58b9-47c3-ab04-017161a56e18]   
2021-05-31T06:15:31.572791+00:00 app[web.1]: [3adfd6f0-58b9-47c3-ab04-017161a56e18] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/auth/failure"):
2021-05-31T06:15:31.572792+00:00 app[web.1]: [3adfd6f0-58b9-47c3-ab04-017161a56e18]
```

Thank you: )

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

It just was copying master.key and replace it as it says below!

```
heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY="copy and paste here config/master.key "
```

[How to get rails master.key after upgrading to rails 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54410016/how-to-get-rails-master-key-after-upgrading-to-rails-5-2)